# How to capture error message in LotusScript

Tags: error-handling, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I want to capture error message in error handler and use it in if condition:

```
errorhandler:
Print "Error in function TriggerMail -- " & Cstr(Error) &  " -- occured at line - " & Cstr(Erl())   
MsgBox CStr(Error)
```

---

```
    If CStr(Error) = "Unable to send mail, no match found in Name & Address Book(s)" Then
        curdoc.Flag = " Invalid Short name"
                Call curdoc.Save(False, True)
             end if
```

I am using cstr(Error) which I got and and validtaing...Though my 'If' condition is true it is skipping the condition.

Please correct me and tell me some alternative way.

Tried using error number still not able to get into if loop

```
Call doc.Send(False, False)

    If Str(Err) = "4294" Then
        curdoc.Flag = " Invalid Short name"
        curdoc.defaulterSLACount = CInt(defaultCount)
        Call curdoc.Save(False, True)
    Else
''---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
' Flags set in the week doc of the defaulter for reference  
    'curdoc.Flag = "Mail Sent Successfully"
    curdoc.SentTo = doc.sendTo
    curdoc.CopiedTo = doc.CopyTo
    curdoc.SentOn = Cstr(Now)
    curdoc.defaulterSLACount = Cint(defaultCount)

    Call curdoc.Save(False, True)
    End If

Else

    curdoc.Flag = "Mail Not Sent"
    curdoc.defaulterSLACount = Cint(defaultCount)
    Call curdoc.Save(False, True)

End If  ' --------------------  DefaulterCount If Check ends here

Exit Function

errorhandler:
Print "Error in function TriggerMail -- " & Cstr(Error) &  " -- occured at line - " & Cstr(Erl())   
MsgBox Str(Err)

Resume Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `Error` I would suggest you to use **[`Err` statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_ERR_STATEMENT.html&resultof=%22err%22%20)** to get the error number and depending on it perform your action.

**Update:**

You need to write your condition `If Str(Err) = "4294" Then` inside the error handler.

```
errorhandler:

    If Str(Err) = "4294" Then
        curdoc.Flag = " Invalid Short name"
        curdoc.defaulterSLACount = CInt(defaultCount)
        Call curdoc.Save(False, True)
    Else
```

Or you could write code to handle error specifically for `4294`

```
... 
... 
... 
On Error 4294 goto AmbiguousError doc.send(True) 
... 
... 
... 
Exit sub 

AmbiguousError: 
Set namesdb= session.getdatabase(db.server, "names.nsf") 
Set Persondoc= namesdb.getview("($Users)").getdocumentbykey(docmail.SendTo(0)) 
docMail.SendTo = Persondoc.fullname(0) & "@" & Persondoc.MailDomain(0) 
Call docMail.Send(True) 
Resume next 
End sub
```

The above code snippet was taken from this **[TechNote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21153854)**.

Comment: If Str(Err) = "4294" Then
   curdoc.Flag = " Invalid Short name"
   curdoc.defaulterSLACount = CInt(defaultCount)
   Call curdoc.Save(False, True) ...I have used Err still not able to get into if loop

Comment: Check if the code is really throwing error? Also may reason why you are converting the `err` to string before comparing?

Comment: yes I have removed str and tried with only err but still it is not working. If i check the code it is going to error handler.

Comment: Just checked your updated code. The condition `If Str(Err) = "4294" Then` should come inside your error handler. Take help of this technote http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21153854

Comment: Call doc.Send(False, False) is not going to error handler though 'To' short id is incorrect since 'CC' and 'BCC' are correct. But my requiremnt is it should not send mail to anyone if 'To' short id is wrong. I am getting 'To' value in doc.SendTo = curdoc.empShortID(0)...Please let me know how can i do this.

Comment: @user1912987: I haven't situation similar to your so I am not aware how can we do it. This could well be another question.

Answer (score 0):

Better use the On Error statement as it's meant to be used:

```
On Error number Goto handler
```

At the start of the function, you can already specify how you want to catch your errors.